# How to submit a form without postback in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a form in asp.net webpage which contains 2 drop down lists and a hyperlink + a button.
I want that if user changes an option is dropdowns to change navigate url.
I have done like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPackages" AutoPostBack ="true" runat="server" 
  onselectedindexchanged="ddlPackages_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and then I have the method defined.

The point is that I don't want to make a submit when I change the drop down. Can I do it using only aspx or I have to use javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to change the href of the hyperlink based on the selected value of the dropdown. You can do this with javascript. Make sure you have `AutoPostBack="false"` and remove the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` attribute as well.

To do it using jQuery, use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(function(){
    var $dropdown = $('#<%= ddlPackages.ClientId %>');
    $dropdown.change(function(){
       //Put logic to decide the link here based on the select value 
       var newPage = 'page' + $dropdown.val() + '.aspx'; 
       $('#linkId').attr('href', newPage);
    });    
});
</script>
```

**Edit:**

In case you absolutely must have the logic for getting the new url based on the drop down value on the server side, you can turn the method into a [Page Method](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) and call it using ajax from the jQuery script above. But you can probably get away with creating the javascript dynamically in the aspx page instead.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1) Wrap the controls in an Update Panel (.NET 3+). Put AutoPostBack=true on the dropdownlist, and define a SelectedIndexChange event for it that changes the hyperlink control's Navigate URL property. When the user changes the dropdown, you're method will fire without the APPEARANCE of a form submission. Downside: there's a slight delay between the dropdown changing and the link changing. If your server is really, really slow, this delay could potentially cause problems (but this is probably unlikely).

2) Use custom JavaScript and do away with your .NET controls completely. This is what I would probably do, assuming you don't need to do anything else with these controls programatically. Your JavaScript function would monitor the dropdown for a SelectedINdexChange and adjust the href attribute of the anchor tag accordingly. Look into jQuery to speed up development if you aren't too familiar with plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `AutoPostBack` you have to post the form using jQuery or Javascript

You can add an event on your drop down list `onchange` and add the code you need to post the form usin jQuery:

```
$('#formId').submit();
```

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

If you to want navigate to another Url add the below code at your `DropDownList` control (make sure `AutoPostBack=false`)

```
onchange="window.location.href='yourUrl'"
```

it would be better put that Javascript on a separate file anyway

Comment: all right but I need when the dropdown is changed to execute a method without submit, how do I do?

Answer (score 0):

If the control is an `ASP:DropDownList`, you can use the `AutoPostBack="True|False"` property to prevent a postback

Comment: all right but I need when the dropdown is changed to execute a method without submit, how do I do?